# What it mean when a problem has a status of -1 after solving in Python's pulp library?

Tags: python, pulp

I've been getting a status code of -1 after solving my linear programming problem.

```py
status = problem.solve()
# status == -1
```

Based on my research, -1 isn't a status code that should even be possible. There are no errors while adding constraints/variables to the problem. I know that the problem is solvable because I have already solved it elsewhere (the code was garbage so I'm  rewriting it). I've tried reinstalling pulp, which didn't work, and I don't know how to begin troubleshooting this. Why am I getting this status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have more detailed information by checking the corresponding status associated with the value. In your case:

```
>>> pulp.LpStatus[-1]
'Infeasible'
```

In general, the possibilities are:

```
>>> pulp.LpStatus
{0: 'Not Solved', 1: 'Optimal', -1: 'Infeasible', -2: 'Unbounded', -3: 'Undefined'}
```

Comment: Thanks! Knowing it was Infeasible helped me find out where I was going wrong when adding constraints.